# How to create an easily customizable Manager for multiple Resource Types

Tags: c++, templates

I'm very new in C++, but I'm working on a little framework of mine.

For this framework, I need to load various types of `Resources` and I would love to write it such it would be very easy to add new `Resources` without having to create managers for every one of them.

So I was thinking like this:

I need base `BaseResource` class from which I can then inherit other resource types

```
class BaseResource {
    uint32_t resource_id;
    std::string name;
    std::string path;

public:
    uint32_t get_id() {
        return resource_id;
    }

    const std::string& get_name() {
        return name;
    }

    const std::string& get_path() {
        return path;
    }
};
```

Then what I need is some kind of base `BaseResourceManager` templated for `Resource`

```
template<class T>
class BaseResourceManager{

    // path = name
    std::vector<T> _resources;
    std::map<std::string, uint32_t> _path_map; // 

public:
    void load(std::string path) {
         // load from file and call T with name
         _path_map.insert();
    }

    T& get(uint32_t idx) {
        return _resources[idx];
    }

    T& get_by_name(std::string name) {
        return _resources[_path_map[name]];
    }

     void delete(uint32_t idx) {
         std::string name = resources[idx].get_name();
        _resources[idx] = null_ptr;
        
        _path_map[name] = nullptr; // ERASE ??
    }


};
```

But now I'm kind of stuck while making something, what could glue multiple `BaseResourceManager<T1>`, `BaseResourceManager<T2>` together.

All I could do, but it is wrong, is this main `ResourceManager`

```
class ResourceManager {
    // managers
    std::vector<BaseManager> managers;

public:

    ResourceManager() {
    }

    void init() {
        
    }

    void register_manager(BaseManager&& man) {
        managers.push_back(man);
    }

template <typename T, size_t i>
    T get() {
        return dynamic_cast<T>(managers[i]);
    }
};
```

I think it would be a good idea to store in `_managers` some kind of pointer to heap-allocated managers,
and also what I couldn't solve was creating `get()` function only with one template, somehow automatically create a sequence of numbers for every type as a second template.

Comment: Have you learned about inheritance and virtual functions yet?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik yes , I did, I just want to provide easy way, how I could easily create new ResourceManagers without having to create many files you know. Because every manager does the same thing.

Comment: And what exactly is `BaseManager`? It is unclear from your question. Perhaps what you are looking for is to simply define a `BaseManager` class that contains nothing but abstract virtual functions, and have the template inherit from `BaseManager` and implement all virtual functions. Then, `ResourceManager` would need to store a vector of `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`s to `BaseManager`s, and the rest would pretty much work, as is.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `BaseManager` is manager for concrete Class inherited from `BaseResource` . And then ResourceManager should 'unity' everything , and also add some way how to add new `BaseManager` by simply calling function

Comment: @SamVarshavchik if I define those functions as `pure virtual` where do i define them then ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231901/discussion-between-patrik-baso-and-sam-varshavchik).

Comment: And where does BaseResourceManager fit into this? It is not used by any of the other code you give. Is it meant to be be templatised Resource classes?

Comment: @Ian4264 It should be templatised Manager for Specific Resource given by template